# Python method for rapidly producing custom synthesized tonal sequences from a terminal window

Tags: python, terminal, dsl, pyparsing, textx

I'm trying to design a method for generating audio signals rapidly. I need this for electrophysiological experiments in which I will play tone sequences for the purpose of examining neuronal responses in the brain's auditory system.

I need to be able to quickly construct a novel sequence in which I can specify features of each tone (e.g. frequency, duration, amplitude, etc.), silent pauses (i.e. rests), and the sequence of tones and pauses.

I want to do this from the terminal using a simple sequence of codes. For instance, entering `tone(440,2) rest(2) tone(880,1) rest(1) tone(880,1)` would generate a "song" that plays a 2-second sine wave tone at 440 Hz, then a 2-second rest, then a 1-second tone at 880 Hz, etc.

I have Python functions for producing tones and rests, but I don't know how to access and control them from the terminal for this purpose. After some reading, it seems like using textX or PyParsing might be good options, but I have no background in creating domain-specific languages or parsers, so I'm not sure. I've completed this [textX tutorial](https://dbader.org/blog/writing-a-dsl-with-python) and read this [PyParsing description](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing), but it's not yet clear how or whether I can use these methods for the rapid, terminal-based audio construction and playback that I need. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just start python or better ipython, import your functions `from somewhere import tone,rest` and call them like `tone(440,2); rest(2)...`? Do you have some specific reason to go DSL route?

Comment: @Igor Dejanović Thanks for your thought. I've considered this, but I'm worried that there might be slight differences in the timing of the events from one playback to the next, which could cause different neuronal responses. Preferably I would be able to rapidly create and playback a .wav generated by the sequence of function outputs so that every time I play that sequence the audio is exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I have provided an initial solution for textX bellow if you choose to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

This would be an initial solution for textX:

```py
from textx import metamodel_from_str

grammar = r'''
Commands: commands*=Command;
Command: Tone | Rest;
Tone: 'tone' '(' freq=INT ',' duration=INT ')';
Rest: 'rest' '(' duration=INT ')';
'''

mm = metamodel_from_str(grammar)

input = 'tone(440,2) rest(2) tone(880,1) rest(1) tone(880,1)'
model = mm.model_from_str(input)

for command in model.commands:
    if command.__class__.__name__ == 'Tone':
        # This command is a tone. Call your function for tone. For example:
        render_tone(command.freq, command.duration)
    else:
        # Call rest. For example:
        render_rest(command.duration)
```

You can also easily take your input recipe from external file by changing above `mm.model_from_str` to `mm.model_from_file`.

Answer (score 1):

This annotated pyparsing example should get you started:

```
import pyparsing as pp
ppc = pp.pyparsing_common

# expressions for punctuation - useful during parsing, but 
# should be suppressed from the parsed results
LPAR, RPAR, COMMA = map(pp.Suppress, "(),")

# expressions for your commands and numeric values
# the value expression could have used ppc.integer, but
# using number allows for floating point values (such as
# durations that are less than a second)
TONE = pp.Keyword("tone")
REST = pp.Keyword("rest")
value = ppc.number

# expressions for tone and rest commands
tone_expr = (TONE("cmd")
             + LPAR + value("freq") + COMMA + value("duration") + RPAR)
rest_expr = (REST("cmd")
             + LPAR + value("duration") + RPAR)

# a command is a tone or a rest expression
cmd_expr = tone_expr | rest_expr

# functions to call for each command - replace with your actual
# music functions
def play_tone(freq, dur):
    print("BEEP({}, {})".format(freq, dur))

def play_rest(dur):
    print("REST({})".format(dur))
```

How it works:

```
cmd_str = "tone(440,0.2) rest(2) tone(880, 1) rest(1) tone( 880, 1 )"

for music_code in cmd_expr.searchString(cmd_str):
    if music_code.cmd == "tone":
        play_tone(music_code.freq, music_code.duration)
    elif music_code.cmd == "rest":
        play_rest(music_code.duration)
    else:
        print("unexpected code", music_code.cmd)
```

Prints:

```
BEEP(440, 0.2)
REST(2)
BEEP(880, 1)
REST(1)
BEEP(880, 1)
```

More info at https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/pyparsing_2.4.7/HowToUsePyparsing.html and module reference at https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/pyparsing_2.4.7/pyparsing.html